# Add a condition to a Powershell forEach

Tags: powershell

I'm still very noob at scripting and I've got to do some scripting in PS which I'm also just recently discovering.

Based on things previously found on stack, I've written this tiny script that checks if machines are online **and** then tries to copy a folder **and** apply proper user rights.

What I would like is to automate it a bit more :

-If I get the error message for all machines, I want the script to start again from the beginning.

-If I get a success message for at least 1 machine, I want the script to stop at the end of its loop and print the successful machine name.

Ideally I also would like the script to remove the successful machine from the txt file at the end of the loop, before starting again.

here's the code

```
$computers=Get-Content c:\listemachines.txt

$source = "C:\Folder"
$destination = "c$\Folder"

ForEach ($COMPUTER in ($computers))
        {if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
        {write-host "Cannot reach $computer is offline" -f red}  #error message
          
else    {
        if ((Test-Path -Path \\$computer\$destination)){
        TRY{
        Copy-Item $source -Destination \\$computer\$destination -force -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Successfully copied on $computer" -BackgroundColor Green
        Get-Acl -Path C:\Folder | Set-Acl -Path "\\$computer\$destination"
        Write-Host "Successfully copied ACL on $computer" -BackgroundColor Green
        }
        Catch {$error[0].exception.message}
        }
        }
        }
```

thanks alot for your help, this website is amazing !

Answer (score 0):

-If I get the error message for all machines, I want the script to start again from the beginning.

You will need some kind of counter logic for this one. It quite simple, just declare a **$i = 0** variable and add a number every time it fails by using **$i++** within the foreach if statement. Once the loop is completed just compare the value to a count of the array.

-If I get a success message for at least 1 machine, I want the script to stop at the end of its loop and print the successful machine name.

Use the **break** command to exit the loop if it was successful. You can print out the name by using **Write-Host $computer** from within the foreach before you break out.

Comment: Thanks alot for your input, okay i'm adding a print of the machine name.


What would I have to change and add for :
- remove the successful machine(s) from the txt file at the end of the loop, and then start over again from start of the file ?

Comment: My advice would be to generate a new array with the failed clients and then output the array to a file. You can do this by declaring *$failedComputer = @()* before the foreach statement and adding the failed computers using *$failedComputer += $computer* then just export the array to overwrite the file once the loop has finished. Caution though, the *break* will exit the loop and not complete the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the strategy and run the code while capturing the results in a CSV file.
That way you can inspect what went wrong for each computer (or what worked as expected):

Something like this:

```
# on first run, use the complete list of computers
$computers = Get-Content -Path 'c:\listemachines.txt'

$source      = 'C:\Folder'
$destination = 'C$\Folder'
$sourceAcl   = Get-Acl -Path $source

$oldErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$result = foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    # create an object for output (details are filled in later)
    $out = [PsCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $computer
        CopyFiles    = $false
        CopyACL      = $false
        Error        = $null
    }
    
    if (!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
        Write-Warning "Cannot reach computer '$computer'"
        $out.Error = "Cannot reach computer '$computer'"
        continue  # skip this one and proceed with the next computer (if any)
    }
    
    try{
        $targetPath = Join-Path -Path "\\$computer" -ChildPath $destination
        # create the path on the remote computer if needed
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory -Force
        # copy the folder contents
        Copy-Item $source -Destination $targetPath -Force -Recurse
        Write-Host "Successfully copied files on $computer" -BackgroundColor Green
        $out.CopyFiles = $true
        # copy the local ACL to the destination folder
        Set-Acl -Path $targetPath -AclObject $sourceAcl
        Write-Host "Successfully copied ACL on $computer" -BackgroundColor Green
        $out.CopyACL = $true
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
        $out.Error = $_.Exception.Message
    }
    # return the object so it gets collected in variable $result
    $out
}
# reset the ErrorActionPreference to what it was
$ErrorActionPreference = $oldErrorAction

# show the results on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save this to a CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\ProcessesComputers.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The next time you run this after you have inspected what went wrong with some computers, load your computers list from **THIS** csv file instead of using `Get-Content -Path 'c:\listemachines.txt'` like this:

```
# these are the computers that failed in the previous run
$computers = (Import-Csv -Path 'C:\ProcessesComputers.csv' | Where-Object { $_.Error }).ComputerName
```